# Gradle compile generated java file

Tags: java, gradle, makefile

I'm trying to convert a big project to use `gradle` from the current state which uses `makefiles`.

I have hit a wall though at some point. Suppose we have the following directory tree (a lot of stuff omitted for simplicity):

```
root
|-- src
|    +-- main
|         +-- java
|              +-- com
|                  +-- app
|                      |-- a
|                      |-- b
|                      +-- c
+-- build.gradle
```

Now lets suppose that in package `com.app.c` exists a java file with a main class which is being used to generate a new java file under the same directory which then should be compiled as well. Package `com.app.c` has dependencies on the other packages as well.

With a makefile you can do something like the following (a simple algorithm):

1. Compile packages `com.app.a` and `com.app.c`.

   Move to the directory of package `com.app.b` and compile only the files required to create the generated file.

   Create the generated file by running the main function in the file used for generation.

   Compile the whole `com.app.b` package which now includes the generated file.

Using gradle though I cannot do something like that (or at least I don't think I can).

What I thought of doing was create a JavaExec task that will run the file that produces the generated java file and make it run after compileJava and also finalized with compileJava. But obviously that is a circular dependency between the tasks and a dead end.

Has anyone ever done or met something similar? If anyone could help I would appreciate it.

Note that I cannot easily move the file generation out of that file as it has some deep dependencies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I didn't search that good.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19418847/1221734) solution works in this case as well.

The difference is that you have to have the following configuration:

```
task generateFile(type: JavaExec) { ... }

task compileGeneratedFile(type: JavaCompile) { ... }

generateFile.mustRunAfter compileJava
generateFile.finalizedBy compileGeneratedFile
generateFile.onlyIf { !file("path/to/file").exists() }
```

This seems to do the trick! Just posting the answer so that anyone with the same issue would find it easier.